# Lookup between two Pandas dataframes using a user-defined comparison function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, string-matching

I have two Pandas dataframes (example is illustrative). Columns `df1['list_of_keywords']` and `df2['list_of_words']` each contain lists of words.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(columns=('some_data','another_data','list_of_keywords'))
df2= pd.DataFrame(columns=('something','something_more','something_else','list_of_words'))
```

df1:

| some_data | another_data | list_of_keywords |
| --- | --- | --- |
| id0001 | 12391 | ['word1', 'word2', 'word3'] |
| id0002 | 3233 | ['word7', 'word8', 'word7'] |

df2:

| something | something_more | something_else | list_of_keywords |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| id_abcd | ref34322 | some comment | ['word5', 'word4', 'word5', 'word4', 'word9'] |
| id_eeed | ref5555 | some comment | ['word5', 'word3', 'word2', 'word4', 'word1'] |

For each of cells in `df1['list_of_keywords']` (source cells) I want to learn if a matching cell in `df2['list_of_words']` (target cell) exists.
A matching cell is defined as one that contains all of the words from the source cell (it may contain other words not in the source cell).
I also want to add a column to df1 to record the match result (`True` if match, `False` if no match).
In the example above, there is a match between df1 and df2 for the first row of df1, but not for the second row of df1.

Here's a function to compare two wordlists, which I'd like to use:

```
def compare_names(wordlist1, wordlist2):
    shorter = wordlist1
    longer = wordlist2
    if len(wordlist2) < len(wordlist1):
        t = shorter
        shorter = longer
        longer = t
    result = all(item in longer for item in shorter)
    return result
```

df1 has approx 50k rows, and df2 has 500-600k rows.
There are about 2-5 words in each of items in 'list_of_keywords' and 3-10 words in each of the items in 'list_of_words', so memory is not an issue.

Question: Aside from explicitly looping through both dataframes, is there a faster/shorter/more Pythonic way how to solve the problem?
I am using Python v3.7, Pandas v1.2.4

Comment: Instead of providing empty dataframe provide some data that will be more helpful

Comment: I have added now an example of showing (conceptually) how the dataframes look like,  and how a match works.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```py
# Setup
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "some_data": ["id0001", "id0002", "id0003"],
        "another_data": [12391, 3233, 3426],
        "list_of_keywords": [
            ["word1", "word2", "word3"],
            ["word7", "word8", "word7"],
            ["word1", "word2", "word4"],
        ],
    }
)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "something": ["id_abcd", "id_eeed", "id_dgef"],
        "something_more": ["ref34322", "ref5555", "ref2963"],
        "something_else": ["some comment", "some comment", "some comment"],
        "list_of_words": [
            ["word5", "word4", "word5", "word4", "word9"],
            ["word5", "word3", "word2", "word4", "word1"],
            ["word1", "word2", "word3", "word4", "word6"],
        ],
    }
)

# Data preparation
lists_of_keywords = df1["list_of_keywords"].values
lists_of_words = df2["list_of_words"].values

# Iterate to find a match
match = {"in_df2": []}
for list_of_keywords in lists_of_keywords:
    search = []
    for list_of_words in lists_of_words:
        if set(list_of_keywords).issubset(set(list_of_words)):
            search.append(True)
        else:
            search.append(False)
    if any(search):
        match["in_df2"].append("True")
    else:
        match["in_df2"].append("False")

df1["in_df2"] = pd.DataFrame(match)

print(df1)
# Outputs
  some_data  another_data       list_of_keywords in_df2
0    id0001         12391  [word1, word2, word3]   True
1    id0002          3233  [word7, word8, word7]  False
2    id0003          3426  [word1, word2, word4]   True
```

Comment: Thanks! So there has to be some iteration. For the matching algorithm, though, I will not use a concatenated string, but will write a short method to compare the lists (because `[word1, word2, word4]` should count as a match for `[word1, word2, word3, word4]`).

Comment: I missed that aspect of your question, sorry. You can do without a helper function and use `sets` instead, see my updated answer with your additional use case satisfied.